# pybind11: Represent union with optional data

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I have a structure that looks like the following:

```cpp
/// Enumeration describing register data types.
typedef enum RegDataType
{
    RegDataType_Unknown       = 0x0,    ///< Unknown register data type.
    RegDataType_ImmMultiData  = 0x1,    ///< Register data type is consecutive register values from a single offset.
    RegDataType_ImmMultiPairs = 0x2,    ///< Register data type is register offset and value pairs.
    RegDataType_IndirectData  = 0x3,    ///< Register data type is consecutive register values from a single offset at
                                        ///  a specified address.
    RegDataType_IndirectPairs = 0x4,    ///< Register data type is register offset and value pairs at a specified 
                                        ///  address.
} RegDataType;


/// Structure representing a register data pair of offset and value.
typedef struct PktRegDataPair
{
    uint32_t offset; ///< The register offset.
    uint32_t value;  ///< The register value.
} PktRegDataPair;

/// Structure representing different types of register data that can be found within a packet.
typedef struct PktRegData
{
    RegDataType type;     ///< Register data type.
    uint32_t    numRegs;  ///< The number of register represented.

    union
    {
        struct
        {
            uint32_t        regOffset;    ///< Starting register offset.
            const uint32_t* pData;        ///< Pointer to consecutive register values.
        } immMultiData;

        struct
        {
            const PktRegDataPair* pData; ///< Pointer to register pairs of offsets/values.
        } immMultiPairs;

        struct
        {
            uint64_t address;    ///< Address of consecutive register values/pairs of offsets/values.
            uint32_t addrOffset; ///< Offset to an existing address. Valid only if address above is zero.
            struct
            {
                uint32_t regOffset;  ///< Starting register offset.
            } data;
        } indirect;
    };
} PktRegData;
```

I would like to wrap this in pybind11 in such a way that when the structure is returned to Python, only the valid member variables are present. Similarly, when loaded from Python, I need to translate it into the PktRegData structure.

I'm at a loss as to the best way to do this in pybind11. I've seen documentation for [custom type casters](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/1176#issuecomment-343312352) and [polymorphic type hooks](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/blob/master/tests/test_tagbased_polymorphic.cpp), but am not sure either is best for my use case.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have bunch of undefined types and don't specify which combinations of types are valid, so can't make a running example, but perhaps the code below gets you underway.

The idea is to use a property to represent the data, so you get a hook and do whatever you want in there in terms of representation (I fleshed out the reading side of thing below, writing would be similar). In the hook, create a placeholder object, check which of the members of the union is valid, then fill the attributes of the placeholder as appropriate.

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/pytypes.h>
#include "PktRegData.h"

namespace py = pybind11;

struct PyRegData {};         // placeholder

PYBIND11_MODULE(PktRegData, m)
{
    py::class_<PyRegData>(m, "RegData", py::dynamic_attr())
        .def(pybind11::init<>());

    py::class_<PktRegData>(m, "PktRegData")
        .def(pybind11::init<>())
        .def_property("data", [](PktRegData &d) -> pybind11::object {
            auto this_mod = py::module::import("PktRegData");
            py::object data_type = this_mod.attr("RegData");
            py::object data_obj = data_type();

            if (d.type == ...) {
            // just one example of setting properties
                data_obj.attr("regOffset") = py::cast(d.immMultiData.regOffset);
            } else if (d.type == ...) {
                ...
            }

            return data_obj;
        }, [](PktRegData& d) {});
}
```

The code above is following your "only the valid member variables are present". Personally, I'd bind all data members as properties and simply raise an ValueError (or AttributeError to stay closer to your design) if an attribute is accessed that is not currently valid.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I've edited the original post to define the undefined enum.

For the most part the enumeration is explicit enough to specify which parts of the structure are valid. The indirect structure is valid for both Indirect enum values, where the `indirect.data` is only valid for `IndirectData`.

This looks extremely useful and I'll try this ASAP. Thanks!